# Java Batch API: listener for handling exceptions thrown from ItemReader.open()

Tags: java, jsr352, java-batch, jberet

Is there any listener interface that one could implement to handle exceptions thrown from `ItemReader.open()` methods? There's plenty of listener interfaces but no one seems to be suitable for this.
i.e. `ItemReadListener` catches only exceptions from `ItemReader.readItem()` (similar to `ChunkListener` or `ItemProcessListener` etc.)

There are `JobListener` and `StepListener` interfaces but these two don't define methods that would be called in case of exception.

Is there any way how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [ChunkListener#onError(Exception e)](https://static.javadoc.io/javax.batch/javax.batch-api/1.0.1/javax/batch/api/chunk/listener/ChunkListener.html#onError(java.lang.Exception)) to "catch" any exception within a chunk.  This will work in certain implementations, like WebSphere Liberty / Open Liberty, but may not work in every implementation (since this was a grey area of the specification).

Comment: `ItemReader.open()` is out of the scope of ChukListener. If I understand the concept correctly  `open()` is called before the chunks are performed. However `ChukListener.onError()` doesn't catch the excpetion. At least in the JBeret implementation of JSR352

Comment: I see.   I work on WebSphere Liberty Batch, where we do call the ChunkListener here.  But in fairness to JBeret, there was certainly room for interpretation of the spec requirements here, and I'm not surprised if they implemented it differently.   I tagged this with `jberet` in case that helps.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case, and for what purpose you want to handle that exception?  I'd like to better understand it to figure out how to address it in JBeret.